# Sonarqube and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I have sonarqube and eclipse with plugin configured for a java project. When I run mvn sonar:sonar - I see results of the build in sonarqube console.

When I make analysis with Eclipse plugin - I see all issues locally in Eclipse, but not on server.
This is because eclipse plugin uses preview mode and sonarque db is not updated (which is good).

Now I would like that every eclipse sonar analysis would run in "analysis mode" - and sonarqube database get updated every time (don't ask why).
Do you know how to enable this behaviour?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't ask why but anyway this is not possible.